# Best way to Add values from two arrays in one dictionary python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
n_cluster = [0,0,1,2,2,.....,499]
len(label) = 1200

nodes =   ['m1094',  'm75','m3','m122'...., 'm1272']
len(nodes) = 1200
```

Such that
n_cluster[i] belongs to nodes[i]

Now I want to create a dictionary as:

```
my_dict = {0:['m1094',  'm75'...],1:['m3','m122'],so on....}
```

{0:[nodes belongs to 0],1:[nodes belongs to 1],.....so on for each n_cluster}

Comment: What is the expected output, can u add some samples ?

Comment: No, it's a different question altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using setdefault

**Data**

```
n_cluster = [0,0,1,2,2,3,3,3,4]
nodes =   ['m74','m75','m76','m77', 'm78','m79','m80','m81', 'm82']
```

**Code**

```
my_dict = {}
for cluster, node in zip(n_cluster, nodes):
  my_dict.setdefault(cluster, []).append(node)
```

**Output**

```
from pprint import pprint as pp
pp(my_dict)


{0: ['m74', 'm75'],
 1: ['m76'],
 2: ['m77', 'm78'],
 3: ['m79', 'm80', 'm81'],
 4: ['m82']}
```

Comment: Is setdefault is a inbuilt function of a dictionary in python?

Comment: @SahilKamboj, Yes it is. A more flexible option is provided by `defaultdict` where you can have default as `int`,  `float`, ..

Comment: @Austin-[comparison between setdefault, get, and defaultdict](https://tomron.net/2014/08/25/setdefault-vs-get-vs-defaultdict/#:~:text=setdefault%20sets%20the%20default%20value,every%20key%20we%20access%20to.&text=As%20the%20dictionary%20size%20grows,set%20and%20list%20perform%20worse).  Seems setdefault is more flexible in that the default can vary by key.  However, it introduces an extra line of code except in the case of append as used here.

Answer (score 1):

1. You may first pair out the two lists

   ```
   pairs = zip(n_cluster, nodes) # [(0, 'm1094'), (0, 'm75'),..., (499, 'm1272')]
   ```
2. Then `groupby` by first item of each, and keep second item in resulting lists

   ```
   from itertools import groupby
   from operator import itemgetter

   res = {clu: [v[1] for v in vals] for clu, vals in groupby(sorted(pairs, key=itemgetter(0)), key=itemgetter(0))}
   print(res) # {0: ['m1094', 'm75'], 499: ['m1272']}
   ```

Answer (score 1):

A good option is to use `defaultdict` and iterating over the zipped values:

```
from collections import defaultdict

n_cluster = [0,0,499]
nodes =   ['m1094', 'm75', 'm1272']

d = defaultdict(list)
for x, y in zip(n_cluster, nodes):
    d[x].append(y)

print(d) 
# {0: ['m1094', 'm75'], 499: ['m1272']}
```